# Passing arguments from a call to a bash script to an Rscript

Tags: r, bash, ubuntu

I have a bash script that does some things and then calls Rscript. Here a simple example to illustrate:

**test.sh:**

```
Rscript test.r
```

**test.r:**

```
args <- commandArgs()
print(args)
```

How can I use `./test.sh hello` on the command line result in R printing hello?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have bash pass all the arguments to the R script using something like this for a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Rscript /path/to/R/script --args "$*"

exit 0
```

You can then choose how many of the arguments from $* need to be discarded inside of R.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the way to deal with this is:

**test.sh:**

```
Rscript test.r $1
```

**test.r:**

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
print(args)
```

The `$1` represents the first argument passed to the bash script.

When calling `commandArgs()` instead of `commandArgs(TRUE)`, it does not pass from bash, but instead it will print other arguments called internally.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding asb's answer:

having "--args" in the line of bash script doesn't work, the "--args" was taken as the literal of real argument that I want to pass into my R script. Taking it out works, i.e. "Rscript /path/to/my/rfile.R arg1 arg2"

bash version: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Rscript version: R scripting front-end version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)

Comment: I found this worked in combination with the TRUE argument passed to commandArgs().