# Pass imput file to R script via command line

Tags: r, command-line-arguments

I have 3 data.frames (tab1, tab2) and I need a R script to combine them with cbind and save the output into another table.

So I do:

```
tab1=read.table("imput_tab1.txt",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
tab2=read.table("imput_tab2.txt",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
myfunction <- function(tab1, tab2 )
{
tab3=cbind(tab1,tab2)
}
write.table(tab3, file="output_table.txt",sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names=T, qmethod = "double", quote=F)
```

I would like to do all this on command line.
Something like

```
R Myscript.r imput_tab1.txt imput_tab2.txt > output_table.txt
```

is that possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633540/passing-arguments-from-a-call-to-a-bash-script-to-an-rscript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547789/command-line-arguments-in-bash-to-rscript/4574903#4574903

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry but I know very little of R programming and I can't catch the answer for my question in the 2 answers you linked me above

Comment: I mean I don't how to structure the script in order to make it interactive with the command line

Answer (score 1):

Your script should be:

```
#the variable args below captures the arguments you pass from the 
#command line i.e. the names of the two files and stores them in a vector
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

tab1=read.table(args[1],header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
tab2=read.table(args[2],header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactor=FALSE)

#you never used your function in your code so just do the below
tab3=cbind(tab1,tab2) #you don't necessarily need a function to cbind two tables

write.table(tab3, file="output_table.txt",sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names=T, qmethod = "double", quote=F)
```

Let's assume that your script above is called test.R

You should run it from the command line as:

```
Rscript test.R imput_tab1.txt imput_tab2.txt
```

And it will work (assuming the files are in the correct place).